# Is it absolutely certain that repeated random selection of integers from 0 to 100 will eventually select every integer?

Tags: probability, dice

I would like to know if one can be absolutely certain, after a number of trials, to circle every integer from 1 to 100 using the following method:

Let's say you write down integers 0 to 100 from left to right. Then take one 6-sided die and roll it. The result gives the number of integers from 0 to move to the right along the number line you wrote down. Circle that number. Do it again, moving along the number line and circling numbers. So if on the first roll the die resulted in a 3, you move 3 spaces from zero to the number 3. If the second roll results in a 5, you move 5 spaces from the number 3, to the number 8. Then circle number 8. So now you have 3 and 8 circled. Do this all the way up through the numbers until the last die roll results in a number that would put you past 100. Call this set of results "layer 1".

Now repeat this again on the exact same set of numbers, with some already circled. This will be called "layer 2". Then do "layer 3" and so on until all numbers from 1 to 100 are circled (if possible).

What I am puzzled by is that common sense tells me that eventually all numbers from 1 to 100 will be circled. This appears to me to be absolutely certain. But the results depend on die rolls, which are based on probability, which says there's a small chance that 1 billion "layers" can still leave one number uncircled. I would guess that a resolution to this would be that there's a limit to how many layers of this there could be before all numbers are circled.

Or is there always going to be some probability that billions of layers of this can be done with still one or more numbers uncircled? I'm interested in seeing the mathematics behind this problem.

Comment: What does one do on later layers if the roll lands you at an already circled number? Roll again? If so there could possibly arise cases where there is a surviving spot one could arrive at on a given layer, and all six spots after it might already be circled. In that case the process must have no continuation. On the other hand, maybe the rule is to skip over already circled ones...

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ be an integer from $1$ to $100$.  During the creation of any given layer $k$ has a chance of at least $\frac16$ of being circled (for most numbers probability is higher because there is more than one way to hit them).  This means that the probability of $k$ being missed on a layer is at most $\frac56$.

So in $n$ layers, the probability of $k$ not being circled is at most $\left(\frac56\right)^n$.  Since this expression goes to $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, we would say that the probability of $k$ never being hit is $0$.  This applies to every integer from $1$ to $100$.

So with probability $1$, all the numbers will eventually be circled.

Comment: The intuitive difficulty is that "probability 1" is not identical with "absolute certainty" since intuitively, it is clear that you **could** keep missing the number 79 forever.

Comment: @Ned, I agree.  Probability $1$ does not mean the event is certain to occur.  Another example is flipping a fair coin until you get heads.  The probability that this process terminates is $1$, and yet the process need not terminate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! These are good responses, giving me something to think about. I'd like to run this through a program through many trials to look for tendencies, any one have an idea for a simple free program that does this? I wouldn't be surprised if someone somewhere has already written a script to do this.

Comment: Another thing I'm interested in is what percentage of integers has been circled after x layers? We can already know that on the first layer each one is being circled first, and at the very least, if all landing on 6 (largest spread), will mean 16 (lower bound of 100/6) numbers have been circled. This is 16% of all available integers. But the second layer may select some that were already circled, so the second layers isn't as likely to choose another 16%, although it's possible. It would be interesting to see how many layers tend to be required in order for x percent of integers to be circled.